# Kafka KStream to KStream join not working for Avro SpecificRecords

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro

I have two KStreams of Avro SpecificRecords that I want to join. I can independently process both the streams but I can't understand the code that I can use to join the two. Here is my code so far:

```
    KStream<String, RecordOne> recOneStream = streamsBuilder.stream(recOneTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), recOneSpecificSerde));
    KStream<String, RecordTwo> recTwoStream = streamsBuilder.stream(recTwoTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), recTwoSpecificSerde));


    // change key to match key of rec two
    KStream<String, RecordOne> recOneChangedKeyStream = recOneStream.selectKey((k, v) -> v.getKeyValue().toString());

    // folowing works
    recOneChangedKeyStream.peek((k, v) -> System.out.println("Key : " + k + " Value : " + v)); // output is as expected here

    // trying to make following work?
    KStream<String, JoinedRecord> joinedRecord = recOneChangedKeyStream.join(recTwoStream, (recOn, recTwo) -> {
                JoinedRecord jr = new JoinedRecord();
                jr.setFieldOne...
                return jr;
            },
            JoinWindows.of(Duration.ofSeconds(60)),
            // if I add following line the code breaks at compile time, if I don't add it then it breaks at runtime
            Joined.with(Serdes.String(), recOneSpecificSerde, recTwoSpecificSerde)
    );
```

So the problem is in the Joined.with. I think I have followed the example correctly:
[confluent-example](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#ktable-ktable-join) as it is also using the Joined.with in a similar way that I have. However, in my case I see the following exception in the IDE:

```
Cannot resolve method 'join(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream<java.lang.String, RecordTwo>, <lambda expression>, org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.JoinWindows, org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Joined<K,V,VO>)'
```

The confluent version installed on my machine is `confluent-7.2.2.tar.gz`

Comment: Hi @Syed, you should specify plase whant client version you're using, because:
- Joined is deprecated when join is between two streams from (2.4) and removed from certain version, you should use instead StreamJoined
- Joined is allowed when you join a KTable

Comment: I installed the confluent-7.2.2.tar.gz - the docs need to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the screenshot below the documentation states that Joined.with should be used. But after reading through the error message in the IDE and then going on the [GitHub examples](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/7.2.2-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/StreamToStreamJoinIntegrationTest.java) I noticed that this document is not updated as the required argument is of type `StreamJoined` instead of Joined
[image: confluent documentation]

Comment: exactly it was deprecated, allowed only when joining a Ktable

Comment: The Javadoc and the Apache Kafka documentation should be your source of truth, not external vendors of Kafka.